# Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 Shortening Video

Tags: premiere, conversion, mp4

I have a video that is 38 minutes and 13 seconds in length but when I convert the video to the H.264 encoding using the 'YouTube HD 720p 29.97' preset the video is converted - but only the first 2 minutes or so.

The video file is of the extension '.avi' and was originally recorded using the Lagarith Loss-less video codec in DXtory - the original file fps is 30.

What can I do to convert the entire video?

Comment: Is it only H.264 that shows this behavior? IOW is this a source issue or a conversion issue?

Answer (score 1):

After selecting File -> Export -> Media, in the Export Settings window that pops up, go to the lower left and make sure that Source Range: Entire Sequence is selected.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.  One is that your work area is highlighting less than the entire sequence.  There is a selectable area (shown by two notches on the timeline) that will normally be the limit of the area that Premiere exports if you leave the defaults.  You can either adjust the selected work area or choose to Entire Sequence as the range to export.

The other, though much less likely possibility, is that you are using a third party H.264 encoder that is in a demo mode and limiting output to two minutes.  It is reasonably common for trial modes of codecs to include a length limitation so that the full quality can be seen but it isn't useful for any major projects, but unless you've installed a third party codec, this isn't a possible cause.  If you had a codec installed in the past however, Premiere may have picked it up and started trying to use it.